# Change values of nearest columns in each rows with for loops. Seeks other "safer" solutions

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

Lets say i have the dataframe `mtcar`

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

In each row for each 5th column starting in column 2 i want to evaluate the value and change the 4 nearest columns to "NA" if they are true otherwise do nothing. 
When mtcars are

```
mtcars[2,2]="NA"

mtcars[3,7]=3

t<-(ncol(mtcars)-1)/5
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars)){
  for (j in 1:t){
    if (mtcars[i,((j-1)*5+2)]<3.01)  {
      mtcars[i,((j-1)*5+3):((j-1)*5+6)]="NA"
    } else if (mtcars[i,((j-1)*5+2)]=="NA"){
      mtcars[i,((j-1)*5+3):((j-1)*5+6)]="NA"
    }
  }
}
```

it works as wanted.

```
mtcars
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6   160 110  3.9  2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  NA    NA  NA   NA    NA 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4   108  93 3.85  2.32  3.00 NA NA   NA   NA
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6   258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8   360 175 3.15  3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6   225 105 2.76  3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8   360 245 3.21  3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69  3.19 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92  3.15 22.90  1  0    4    2
```

but when

```
mtcars[8,7]="NA"

mtcars

                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6   160 110  3.9  2.62 16.46 NA NA   NA   NA
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  NA    NA  NA   NA    NA 17.02 NA NA   NA   NA
Datsun 710          22.8   4   108  93 3.85  2.32     3 NA NA   NA   NA
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6   258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44 NA NA   NA   NA
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8   360 175 3.15  3.44 17.02 NA NA   NA   NA
Valiant             18.1   6   225 105 2.76  3.46 20.22 NA NA   NA   NA
Duster 360          14.3   8   360 245 3.21  3.57 15.84 NA NA   NA   NA
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69  3.19    NA NA NA   NA   NA
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92  3.15  22.9 NA NA   NA   NA
```

then all the columns are changes to "NA" which is not wanted. I would really appreciate any help to change my for loop or create a new function, that only changes the COLUMNS in the wanted row and not change the NA's in all the rows.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it seems so arbitrary that it makes me wonder if this is a case of the XY problem. I have a suspicion that the columns here represent dimensions, and that it will be simpler and more computationally efficient if you first convert your data into tall, or "tidy" form.
 https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I see what you mean, i have edited my post to be more specific what i really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure how to correct the logic of your loop, so I tried a tidyverse solution which gave the expected result.

First I converted to a "long" / "tidy" form (which takes a little extra work for `mtcars`).

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars_tidy <- mtcars_mod %>%
  rownames_to_column("model") %>% 
  gather(stat, value, -model) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(model:stat), forcats::as_factor) %>%  # as_factor to preserve order
  # BTW, the character "NA"s aren't numeric, so convert to missing value NA's 
  mutate(value = value %>% as.numeric()) %>%
  arrange(model) %>%
  group_by(model) %>% mutate(col_num = row_number()) %>% ungroup()

head(mtcars_tidy, 14)
```

Now I add the NA's using your rules. To confirm it's working, first I flag the rows that should trigger following NA's. Then, within each group, I replace the values for the next four entries. I'm sure there are more concise & faster ways to do this, but I wanted to make the process clear.

```
mtcars_NA_applied <- mtcars_tidy %>%
  # Test looks for values under 3.01 or missing (NA), only in certain rows
  mutate(test = (value < 3.01 | is.na(value)) & col_num %% 5 == 2) %>%

  # Now we change the next four values. I'm sure there's a more elegant way!
  group_by(model) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(lag(test,1) ~  NA_real_,
                           lag(test,2) ~  NA_real_,
                           lag(test,3) ~  NA_real_,
                           lag(test,4) ~  NA_real_,
                           TRUE        ~  value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # Now remove the helper columns and make the table wide again
  select(-col_num, -test) %>%
  spread(stat, value)
```

Seems to work.

```
    > head(mtcars_NA_applied, 8)
# A tibble: 8 x 12
  model               mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <fct>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Mazda RX4          21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21      NA   NA     NA NA    NA     17.0     0     1     4     4
3 Datsun 710         22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32   3      NA    NA    NA    NA
4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
6 Valiant            18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
7 Duster 360         14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
8 Merc 240D          24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  NA      NA    NA    NA    NA
```

**Sample data**

```
mtcars_mod<- mtcars
mtcars_mod[2,2]="NA";   
mtcars_mod[3,7]=3; 
mtcars_mod[8,7]="NA"
mtcars_mod
```